C Macro Expansion Again
I have the following:
#define HEADER_SYMBOLS(i)   \
    i(WIFI_BARS_0, IconWifiBars0)\
    i(WIFI_BARS_1, IconWifiBars1)\
    i(WIFI_BARS_2, IconWifiBars2)\
    i(WIFI_BARS_3, IconWifiBars3)\
    i(WIFI_BARS_FULL, IconWifiBarsFull)\

enum EnHeaderSymbols
{
#define CREATE_HEADERICON_ENUM(e,f)  SYMBOL_##e,
    HEADER_SYMBOLS(CREATE_HEADERICON_ENUM)
    NUM_HEADER_SYMBOLS
};

#define HEADER_SYMBOL_EXTERNS(e,f) extern const lv_img_dsc_t f;
HEADER_SYMBOLS(HEADER_SYMBOL_EXTERNS)

which [ whether done right or wrong! ] gives me the enum values from the HEADER_SYMBOLS table and spins out a bunch of extern references to the external lv_img_dsc_t structures
however what I also want is
static lv_img_dsc_t headerSymbolImages[NUM_HEADER_SYMBOLS] = { IconWifiBars0, IconWifiBars1 .. } ;

to be ideally initialised from the struct names IconWifiBars0 etc so I have an array of the objects as well as the enum names to refer back to them elsewhere
I so far realise isn't do-able directly as its the whole initialising from non const stuff, or it could be built at runtime when the for 0 to NUM_HEADER_SYMBOLS loop is running creating various things anyway. however for that I need a way to essentially be able to use HEADER_SYMBOLS as an array type thing indexable which it clearly isnt
is there a better / proper way to achieve this as there are a load more symbols to declare and it would be nice if the for loop that creates all the objects when it initialises doesn't have to go back and manually have the IconWifiBarsxxx names hard coded
thanks in advance for enlightenment!

I don't see how headerSymbolImages makes any sense as written, if the initializers are structs declared elsewhere. If it was valid you'd end up copying structs by value and end up with duplicate data. Shouldn't this rather be a lv_img_dsc_t* pointer array, pointing at structs defined elsewhere?
In addition to avoiding duplicate data, initializing pointers with static storage duration can be done, address constants are valid initializers:
static const lv_img_dsc_t* const headerSymbolImages[] =   // note empty array size
{ 
  #define HEADER_SYMBOL_REF(e, f) &(f),  // &(IconWifiBars0),
  HEADER_SYMBOLS(HEADER_SYMBOL_REF)
} ;

// ensure array integrity:
static_assert(sizeof(headerSymbolImages)/sizeof(*headerSymbolImages) == NUM_HEADER_SYMBOLS, 
              "headerSymbolImages not in sync with enum EnHeaderSymbols");

Alternatively, you could skip this array and make a big union containing such an array, as well as a list of individually named struct items. Then only allocate memory as a single union object.

... or declare the array only, and make the IconWifiBarsX be macros expanding to references to array elements.  That would need to be structured differently, though, as you can't use macros to define other macros.
